# ng-switch element in layout issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

I am using ng-switch to create a filtering input field in the layout. I am switching on the route name and I use this field to filter the data in ng-repeat on each page.

```
div(ng-controller="NavbarCtrl", ng-switch on="route.current.name")
                input.filter(ng-switch-when='offers',type="text", ng-model="$parent.$parent.search.title")
                input.filter(ng-switch-when='merchants',type="text", ng-model="$parent.$parent.search.name")
```

The problem with this approach is that the value that I input on one page stays saved when navigating to the other route and filters data on the other page as well. I am using the inbuilt angular search filter, hence the model names.

Can I somehow reset the value of the filter on route change?

Another issue is that I find this $parent.$parent scope access impractical, but i couldn't find a more elegant way.

Any hints greatly appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't have to use `$parent` if you are using an object in the parent scope. I.e., if `$scope.search = { ... }` is defined in the parent scope, child scopes (but not directive isolate scopes) can access this object via [normal JavaScript prototypal inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs).

Comment: `$route.current.name` maybe ??

Comment: on the offers route I have a data table as such tr(ng-repeat="o in offers | filter:search") td {{offer.title}} etc. I can't reach it from the layout with ng-model='search.title'

Comment: This should work.  I can only guess that you have an isolate scope in between somewhere.

Comment: the 2 scopes have only the $rootScope as common ancestor, both their parents scopes are children of the rootscope

Comment: If `search` is explicitly defined as an object on the $rootScope (e.g., in `run()` you could have `$rootScope.search = {}`), then all descendant (non-isolate) scopes should be able to access it via prototypal inheritance.

Comment: search is the inbuilt angular js filter

Comment: The built-in filter is [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter).  On that page, in the example app, `search` is just a $scope property that `filter` uses.  You can name that property whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you, now i get it. I misunderstood the filter. Renaming the search variable solved my problem. If you post that as an answer, I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the confusion was around the `search` property, which is not a special filter in Angular, but just the name of a property that will be used with Angular's [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter) filter.

Also, `$parent` is not needed if a property on a parent scope object is used/referenced. I.e., if `$scope.search = { ... }` is defined in the parent scope, child scopes (but not directive isolate scopes) can access this object via [normal JavaScript prototypal inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs).